# How to force HAProxy load balancer to redirect specific URLs always to the same server?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, https, haproxy

My domain is using HAProxy as a load balancer, there are 3 servers balanced, but I want to execute some particular urls always on the same server.
Is this possible?

or maybe this is an XY problem and there is a better solution:
In some urls I'm creating files, I want to create the files always in one of my fron servers because that one has an rsync to the others.

EDIT: Is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041131/can-haproxy-direct-a-request-to-a-particular-server
But the problem is my HAProxy is not managing the SSL, so I cannot create the ACL rule based on the path (or at least I don't know how).

Comment: Sounds like a bit of an XY problem, but hard to tell. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want traffic switched based on the URL? That's pretty easy, normally. You'd configure haproxy to read the URL or a header or even something deeper in the body of the request.

But if the http is encrypted as it passes through, haproxy can't read any of that. In fact, to haproxy, that would probably just look like a TCP connection - it wouldn't know it was HTTP.

Comment: OK, I think you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041131/can-haproxy-direct-a-request-to-a-particular-server

Comment: The problem is my HAProxy is not managing the SSL, so I cannot create an ACL rule based on the URI because is not accessible, do you know some workaround?